# Is it correct to pass reference of object A to object B, so that B can access fields and methods of A directly using A's reference?

Tags: java

Is it correct to use the fields and methods of a class in this way:-

```
//Class A
class Main
{
    //Fields that are also needed by the "Player" object
    String[] moveArray;
    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;
    int leftLimit; 
    int rightLimit; 
    int upLimit;
    int downLimit; 
    boolean left;
    boolean right;
    boolean up;
    boolean down;
    //and more

    private Player player=new Player();;


    public void run() 
    {
        //Pass this object's reference to the "Player" object, before entering the infinite loop
        player.main=this;

        while(isRunning)
        {
            update();
            repaint();
        }
    }
} 

//Class B
class Player 
{
    //stores "Main" object's reference
    Main main;

    float playerX;
    float playerY;

    //Accessing the fields that are inside the "Main" object, using its reference 
    private void moveLR()
    {
        if(main.left)
        {
            playerX-=0.5f;
        }
        else if(main.right)
        {
            playerX+=0.5f;
        }
    }

    private void moveUD()
    {
        if(main.up)
        {
            playerY-=0.5f;
        }
        else if(main.down)
        {
            playerY+=0.5f;
        }
    }

    public void update(){
        if(playerX > main.leftLimit && playerX < main.rightLimit)
        {
            moveLR();
        }
        if(playerX > main.upLimit && playerX < main.downLimit)
        {
            moveUD();
        }
    }
}
```

There will be too many getters and setters if I use them, since the project would contain many classes, each containing many methods requiring the use of other objects' members. Is the above process correct, or is declaring the fields private and accessing all of them using getters/setters the best possible way? Thanks!

Comment: Any IDE will make it trivial to generate getters and setters. Use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware of the code smell named [Feature envy](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/feature-envy)?

Often, you want to access a lot of neighbor's fields, without realizing that those fields would better fit/move to the class that uses them the most.

Moreover, OOP by essence is "passing message" to neighbor.
**Avoid getters/setters when you can** (very often => 95% of use cases) and follow the [Tell! Don't Ask!](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) philosophy.
The idea is to **tell** neighbors for **behavior**, not **asking** for data.
=> That's the biggest difference with a procedural language like C.

IMO, `Player` should `tryToMoveTo`, and if successful, `update` should occur to the `area`:

```
public void tryToMoveTo(direction Direction) {
    if(this.canMoveTo(direction)) 
      area.update(direction); //I tell to update, not ask for coordinates that would make the player responsible for data that doesn't concern it at all.
    else
      throw new InvalidPlayerMove();  
}
```

Avoiding all the ugly getters and setters.

Comment: That Main class is a KeyListener. Whenever "up", "down", "left" or "right" key is pressed, a value is stored in an array (named as "movementArray") in the Main object. Other objects (e.g. "Player", "Map" etc.) also require the movementArray. So, by the "Tell! Don't Ask!" philosophy that you suggested, should i pass the movementArray from the "Main" object to other objects?

Comment: @JustAnotherOne Look at the Observer Pattern ( GOF design pattern), it would solve your specific case in a way that you could drop any of your getters. Merely the `Main` will notify `Player` about move to do, without passing Player asking for Main's data => full encapsulation so great OOP design.Your player will observe, and the area ( Main) will be the observable. This would be a good alternative, although similar, to my previous design except that you chose to make the Player listening for move. I chose to make the Player Move then update the area if valid => more suited to the real world

Comment: To simply answer to your question : "should i pass the movementArray from the "Main" object to other objects?" Try to NEVER break the encapsulation of data. That's the essence of OOP. And that...would break it.

Comment: Thanks. One last question - does passing reference of one object to another breaks encapsulation?

Comment: The idea is to avoid knowing implementation details of its neighbors. Less we know, better it could evolve without impacting us. Telling to do rather than asking to do is the best way to have a real clean and maintenable code in OOP. Read this: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-law-of-demeter-java-examples  it deals with "Law of Demeter", answering your last question. Actually, as long as you can tell, tell! =>  The object that owns data SHOULD/MUST do the action you want. There is time when we have to get:  for reading data, but not for making a behavior from this data. OOP design is art :)

Answer (score 0):

Use getters and setters. It will save you so many headaches later when you decide to add more logic.

Comment: OOP is the opposite of Procedural code; so don't add getters/setters when you don't REALLY need them.